# 51-android.rules for Nexus 5

Tags: android, bootloader, udev, nexus-5

I am having trouble writing the android rules file for my **Nexus 5** on Ubuntu 14.04. I have created a new rules file as instructed in the android developer site, but I still cannot detect my device in the boot mode.

My 51-android.rules contains the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
```

When I try to enter `adb devices` in the terminal, it shows nothing. Can anyone help me out with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/04/universal-udev-rule-for-all-android.html

Answer (score 0):

`adb devices` shows devices in `ADB` and `recovery` modes only. You need to use `fastboot` tool to control an Android device in the boot mode.

Comment: Hey @AlexP. thanks for pointing out the mistake, I had it wrong all this time. I was trying to do ADB in the boot mode which doesn't make any sense. Later, I realized that and tried the **fastboot** command which worked.